# Iteration order for views derived from Guava ImmutableTable

Tags: java, collections, iteration, guava

Does the derived views from a guava immutable table retain insertion order in the original provided table?

For example, consider the "original provided table" as below.

```
ImmutableTable<String, String, String> table = ImmutableTable.<String, String, String>builder()
.put("r1", "c1", "v1")
.put("r2", "c1", "v2")
.put("r3", "c1", "v3")
.put("r4", "c2", "v4")
.build();
```

Now If I operate on

```
table.column("c1").entrySet().iterator()
```

will the iteration provide results in the insertion order "original provided table"?

Note: As per [documentation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayTable.html) iteration on views derived from ArrayTable preserves the insertion order in original table. The use case I have is more leaning towards use of an immutable table.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See the [JavaDoc of ImmutableTable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableTable.html).

> An immutable Table with reliable user-specified iteration order.

PLUS:

- `ImmutableTable.column()` returns an `ImmutableMap` which is *with reliable user-specified iteration order* in [JavaDoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html).
- For an immutable data structure, 'iteration order' should be behavior of its view I think.
- For 'user-specified iteration order', [ImmutableTable.Builder#orderColumnsBy](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/ImmutableTable.html) can achieve.

Comment: I was asking about views derived from immutable table, not the table itself. In the example, the column("c1") routine will yield a map. The order of iteration on the map (the derived view) is the one which lacks clarity.

Comment: @maggu Yes. 

For an immutable data structure,  'iteration order' should be behavior of its view.